# Cache static function result in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, ios8

I have a static function that generates a `UIColor` object so it can be reused several times throughout the application. I don't want this code to run every time, but really just the first time and place it into cache, then let any subsequent retrieval grab it from cache. Only caveat is this value can change so I don't want to permanently persist this value, but only persist it to memory so if the app is restarted, it will grab the latest value and use it throughout its lifecycle.

Here is what my function looks like:

```
class AppConfig: NSObject {   
    static func getGlobalTintColor(alpha: Float = 1) -> UIColor! {
        let colors = split(someVarFromInfoPlist) { $0 == "," }
        let red = CGFloat(colors[0].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let green = CGFloat(colors[1].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let blue = CGFloat(colors[2].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

I don't want `getGlobalTintColor` to run that logic every time. So how to I cache it the first time and let it be served for the rest of the app's lifecycle?

Comment: As you've given it, this is impossible since you pass a parameter (`alpha`). You can't automatically cache the results of an arbitrary function that takes arguments. If you remove the parameter, then see @matt's answer is useful.

Comment: @RobNapier He can do it even with the `alpha` if he configures that first as another static variable.

Comment: do you plan on caching the alpha from the first call or will that stay modifiable?

Comment: Is there any reason why the func returns an implicitly unwrapped optional? Why isn't that a non-optional?

Comment: Good catch on the variable alpha. I actually missed that detail! Maybe the UIColor can be cached then the alpha can be applied after the fact on the UIColor on each call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a `static` *variable* rather than a *function*. Give the variable an initializer function that creates the color.

```
class AppConfig: NSObject {
    static var alpha : CGFloat = 1
    static var globalTintColor : UIColor = {
        // figure out color once, possibly based on `alpha`
        return theColor
    }()
}
```

This works because the static `var` initializer is *lazy*; it can depend on your `alpha` and it will not be initialized until you actually ask for its value for the first time. Moreover, the initializer function *will not run again* thereafter (unless you quit and relaunch the app), which is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like this:

```
class AppConfig: NSObject {   
    private static var tintColor: UIColor?

    static func getGlobalTintColor(alpha: Float = 1) -> UIColor! {
        if tintColor == nil {
            let colors = split(someVarFromInfoPlist) { $0 == "," }
            let red = CGFloat(colors[0].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
            let green = CGFloat(colors[1].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
            let blue = CGFloat(colors[2].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
            tintColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
        }
        return tintColor!.colorWithAlphaComponent(CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function returning a function, caching its return value into a property, and then invoke the function stored in that property to calculate the actual color depending from alpha.

This is the "caching" function:

```
private static func _getGlobalTintColor() -> (Float) -> UIColor {
    let colors = split(someVarFromInfoPlist) { $0 == "," }
    let red = CGFloat(colors[0].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
    let green = CGFloat(colors[1].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
    let blue = CGFloat(colors[2].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
    return { alpha in UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha)) }
}
```

As you can see, it returns a function with signature `(Float) -> UIColor`, i.e. taking the alpha as parameter and returning a color.

Next, a static property is initialized with the return value of this function:

```
private static let globalColor = AppConfig._getGlobalTintColor()
```

Last, the exposed static function takes an alpha parameter, and invokes the function stored in that property to obtain and return the color:

```
static func getGlobalTintColor(alpha: Float = 1) -> UIColor {
    return self.globalColor(alpha)
}
```

Note that the first private function can be removed, and have the property initialized with an inline closure:

```
class AppConfig: NSObject {
    private static let globalColor: Float -> UIColor = {
        let colors = split(someVarFromInfoPlist) { $0 == "," }
        let red = CGFloat(colors[0].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let green = CGFloat(colors[1].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let blue = CGFloat(colors[2].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        return { alpha in UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha)) }
    }()

    static func getGlobalTintColor(alpha: Float = 1) -> UIColor {
        return self.globalColor(alpha)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is brilliant!! Still having a hard time grasping how the return closure is being cached in memory while keeping the alpha dynamic.

Comment: @TruMan1: That's done through captures - I recommend reading [Capturing Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting into a lazy `static` constant with a fixed alpha and a separate function to specify the alpha:

```
class AppConfig: NSObject {    
    static let globalTintColor: UIColor = {
        let colors = split(someVarFromInfoPlist) { $0 == "," }
        let red = CGFloat(colors[0].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let green = CGFloat(colors[1].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        let blue = CGFloat(colors[2].toInt() ?? 0) / CGFloat(255)
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }()

    static func globalTintColor(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return globalTintColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the alpha input can vary throughout the app, you may to consider using an NSCache where the key is a string formed from the color and alpha and the value is the UIColor wrapped in a holder NSObject subclass.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/

The NSCache would be declared as:

```
private static let cache = NSCache()
```